# Magento2 Solr Different Types of Commit

Tags: magento2, search, reindex, solr, magento2-enterprise

It would be helpful if someone could clarify what are the different indexation mode in Magento2 for Solr search.

[image]

What are the difference, advantages and disadvantages of different indexation mode

1. Partial commit
2. Full commit
3. Engine auto commit